# Decrypt AES-128 encrypted data on iOS

Tags: ios, encryption, aes

I am trying to decrypt [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) encrypted data (encrypted in .NET), but my decrypted result string appears to be non-readable, and I don't get any errors.

The data was encrypted using:

- Padding: PKCS7Padding
- KeySize: 128
- Mode: CBC,

I have InItVector, PassCode, salt, and NumberOfPassword (3) iterations.

Here is my code:

```
//I am retrieving my encrypted data from sqlite database:
NSString *strEncryptedData = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_blob(mysqlStatement, 0)];
NSData *dataToDecrypt = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:strEncryptedData options:0];

NSString *password = @"somesecurepassword";
NSData *saltData = [@"mysalt" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *ivData = [@"myIV16charvalue1" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;

NSData *decryptedData = [RNCryptManager decryptedDataForData:encoded password:password iv:ivData salt:saltData HMACSalt:NULL HMAC:NULL error:&error];

NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"decrypted string: %@", str);
```

//Here is the code to encrypt the data on the .NET side:

```
static string hashAlgorithm = "SHA1";
static int passwordIterations = 3;
static string initVector = "myIV16charvalue1";
static int keySize = 128;
static string passPhrase = "somesecurepassword";
static string saltValue = "mysalt";

public static string EncryptData(string plainText)
{
    byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector);
    byte[] saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);
    byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

    PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(
        passPhrase,
        saltValueBytes,
        hashAlgorithm,
        passwordIterations);

    byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keySize / 8);

    RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();

    // It is reasonable to set encryption mode to Cipher Block Chaining
    // (CBC). Use default options for other symmetric key parameters.
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    symmetricKey.BlockSize = 128;
    symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;


    ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(
        keyBytes,
        initVectorBytes);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,
        encryptor,
        CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    // Start encrypting.
    cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);

    // Finish encrypting.
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

    memoryStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();

    string cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);

    return cipherText;
}
```

Comment: Post the code that encrypted in .net

Comment: added code that encrypted data in .net...

Comment: Did you finally find a way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several errors here. It looks like `decryptedDataForData:...` is a modified version of [RNCryptManager](https://github.com/rnapier/ios5ptl/blob/master/ch11/CryptPic/CryptPic/RNCryptManager.m), but there have been several mistakes injected. In particular, it looks like the author copied the encryption method (`encryptedDataForData:...`), and then just changed the operation. You can't do that. The decryption method is different from the encryption method. In the above code, the decryptor ignores the salt and IV that are passed to it, and creates random ones (which is how the encryptor works, not the decryptor).

Some other issues:

- In your encryptor, you're setting the PBKDF2 iterations to 3. In the decryptor you're setting them to 2. This value is very, very low BTW. It is usually at least 1000, and more often at least 10,000.
- Your IV is the wrong length. It has to be exactly 16 bytes. Ideally the IV should be different for every message, and should be sent along to the decryptor. If you have a static IV, then you reduce the security of the encryption.
- While not a cause of your issue, the salt should also random for every message and sent along to the decryptor. A static salt makes it much easier to perform password attacks.

---

EDIT: (Note that you're still using a hacked version of `encryptedDataWithData:` to do decryption. I recommend using the `decryptedDataWithData:` method linked above. The way you've hacked `encryptedDataWithData:` will likely work, but just because the buffer it creates happens to be too long.)

The deeper problem is that you're using the wrong KDF in C#. You're using `PasswordDeriveBytes` which implements PBKDF1. You should be using [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which implements PBKDF2.

Note that there is a bug in the version of RNCryptManager that you're using. In `AESKeyForPassword:salt:`, this line:

```
password.length,  // passwordLength
```

Should be:

```
[password lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:UTF8StringEncoding],
```

Comment: Rob, thank you very much for commenting on my issue.  Yes, the "decryptedDataForData" method is the modified version of RNCryptManager (encryptedDataForData) from your article "Properly encrypting with AES with CommonCrypto" (very informative btw).  I've updated my code to use the IV/Salt values supplied, instead of generating random ones. Also, I changed the PBKDF2 to 3 to match the encryption.  The IV value is 16 bytes, I just replaced it with some text for this post.  However, I still get unreadable string after decryption with no errors :(

Comment: Rob, thank you for your comments, I now use the RNCryptManager's 'decryptedDataForData' method, however I still get the same unreadable decrypted string.  I don't have control of the .net encryption, is there a way to modify the code to use PBKDF1 when decrypting and not PBKDF2? Thank you again.

Comment: CommonCrypto does not provide a PBKDF1 implementation. You could use cryptopp or botan which provide C++ implementations (though they're pretty big packages for one function). Or you can search around for C implementations you can adapt. The spec is here: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2898#section-5.1